# Primitive element of extension $k(T_1,\dots,T_n)/k(T_1,\dots,T_n)^{S_n}$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Let $k$ be a field, consider the field $k(T_1,\dots,T_n)$ with $S_n$ action $\sigma\to (T_i\mapsto T_{\sigma{(i)}})$.

Then by Galois theory, $k(T_1,\dots,T_n)/k(T_1,\dots,T_n)^{S_n}$ is Galois extension, so it can be generated by one element, namely there exist an $a\in K(T_1,\dots,T_n)$, such that $k(T_1,\dots,T_n)=k(T_1,\dots,T_n)^{S_n}(a)$

How can we pick explicitly such a primitive element $a$?

For example, if $n=3$, does $a=T_1$ work? I am not sure, if we pick out $T_1$, how do we play on the symmetric fractions to get $T_2$?

Comment: $k(T_1,\dots,T_n)^{S_n}$ is the fixed field of $S_n$, namely the fraction field of the symmetric polynomials ?

Comment: Hint: How many elements of the Galois group will map the polynomial
$a=T_1+T_2^2+\cdots +T_n^n$ to itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Galois group of this extension is $S_n$ so a primitive element has order $n!$. $T_1$ has order $n$. From the proof of the primitive element theorem we have that there is a generator of the form $$\sum a_iT_i$$for some $a_i\in k$. You might try investigating $\sum i T_i$.

Comment: +1: My inner nitpicker wants to comment that A) the suggested element will work if the characteristic of $k$ is larger than $n$, but not otherwise. B) the proof of the primitive element theorem may make it necessary to allow $a_i\in k(T_1,T_2,\ldots,T_n)^{S_n}$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Good point, that's really what I meant, course, by now I am just phoning in my answers. But an element $x$ is primitive iff all $\sigma(x)$ are distinct, which for the expression in by answer is the same as all $a_i$ (assumed to be in $k$) are distinct, do you agree ?

Comment: Yes. I agree.${}$